# how detect role user in django template?

Tags: django, authentication, permissions

In my template, i want detect if the user connected is an traveller or admin.
This is an example of my model. 
Note: User class is user django model class

[image: Example model]

I see "has_perm" but I haven't got permissions I want roles.

"is_authenticated()" but user admin and user traveller are authenticate.

"is_superuser" but i don't want many super user django admin

I used in spring the tag "hasRole('Admin') but in django i don't see the alternative.

[image: My models]

Thanks!!

Comment: How are your models defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you should be able to put static properties on the classes themselves to dictate whether they are an Administrator or a Traveller without the usage of `isinstance`.

```
class Administrator(User):
    ...

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_traveller(self):
        return False



class Traveller(User):
    ...

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return False

    @property
    def is_traveller(self):
        return True
```

Comment: how can I use this in the template?

Comment: They are properties on the model. You can access them exactly how you would the fields such as ```coins```, ```reputation```, etc.